# Problema com dados repetidos na tabela PHP

Tags: php, for, while

Estou com uma duvida, ao fazer um select para preencher um campo se ele for igual a real ele deveria preencher ex: o item  1 no valor de 1 real o item 2 no valor de 2 e o item no valor de 3, porem nos três itens ele preenche apenas com o 1º item.

o código Controller:

```
public function getItensNF()
{
    $tipNota = @addslashes($_POST['tipNota']);
    $codFil = @addslashes($_POST['codFil']);
    $numNota = @addslashes($_POST['numNota']);
    $codSnf = @addslashes($_POST['codSnf']);

    switch($tipNota)
    {
        case 'Entrada':
            $itemNFSaida = $this->step5ModelObj->getItemNFEntrada(10, $codFil, $numNota, $codSnf);
            $seqCmp = 'SEQIPC';
            $qtdFatRec = 'QTDREC';
            break;

        case 'Saida':
            $itemNFSaida = $this->step5ModelObj->getItemNFSaida(10, $codFil, $numNota, $codSnf);
            $seqCmp = 'SEQIPV';
            $qtdFatRec = 'QTDFAT';
            break;

        default:
            $itemNFSaida = array();
    }

    $parameters = "'$tipNota','$codFil','$numNota','$codSnf'";
    echo '
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").on("click", function(){
        var botao = $(this);
        botao.prop("disabled", true);
        var texto = botao.find("span").text();
        botao.find("span").text("Aguarde...");

        botao.removeClass("btn-primary");
        botao.addClass("btn-danger");
        setTimeout(function(){
           botao.prop("disabled",false);
           botao.removeClass("btn-danger");
           botao.addClass("btn-primary");
           botao.find("span").text(texto);
        },12000
        );



    });
    </script>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button id="btnProcessar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="processEntSai('.$parameters.');"><span>Processar</span></button>
        </div>

        <div class="row">   
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table cellpadding="5" id="tableItemNota" class="display dataTable cell-border compact" cellspacing="0" style="textalign:center; border-bottom:1px solid black;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="border: 1px solid #ccc">
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Item</th>
                            <th>Imagem</th>
                            <th>Qtd</th>
                            <th>U.Medida</th>
                            <th>Peso</th>
                            <th>C&oacute;digo</th>
                            <th>N&ordm; S&eacute;rie</th>
                            <th>Tamanho</th>
                            <th>Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o</th>
                            <th>Coef.</th>
                            <th>Moeda</th>
                            <th>Valor Unit&aacute;rio</th>
                            <th>Valor Total</th>
                        </tr>    
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>';

            foreach($itemNFSaida as $item) {
                if(file_exists('uploads/produtos/'.$item['CODREF'].'.JPG')){
                    $img_url = BASE_URL.'/uploads/produtos/'.$item['CODREF'].'.JPG';
                } else {
                    $img_url = BASE_URL.'/assets/images/imgNotFound.png';
                }                        

                if($item['QTDDEV'] == $item[$qtdFatRec]){
                    $tdSelectBox = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span>';
                } else{
                    $tdSelectBox = '<input type="checkbox" id="'.$item['NUMSEP'].'" name="checkSeq" value="'.$item[$seqCmp].'"/>';
                }                      

                if($item['USU_MOEVEN'] == 'AU'){
                    $item['valorEnt'] = $this->step5ModelObj->TotalentSaiComNota(10, $codFil, $numNota);   

                   $item['PREUNI'] = $item['valorEnt']['USU_VLRMOE'];

                }
                echo '<tr>
                            <td class="order">'.$tdSelectBox.'</td>
                            <td>'.$item[$seqCmp].'</td>
                            <td><img src="'.$img_url.'" id="imgItemPed" data-codpro="'.$item['CODPRO'].'" onclick="itemModalDetalhes(this)"" style="width: 75px; border-radius: 5px; margin: 0px; cursor: pointer;"></td>
                            <td>'.number_format($item['QTD'], 2, '.', '').'</td>
                            <td>'.$item['UNIMED'].'</td>
                            <td>'.number_format($item['PESBRU'], 2, '.', '').'</td>
                            <td>'.$item['CODPRO'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$item['NUMSEP'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$item['CODDER'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$item['CPL'].'</td>
                            <td>'.number_format($item['USU_PREVEN'], 2, '.', '').'</td>
                            <td>'.$item['USU_MOEVEN'].'</td>
                            <td>'.number_format($item['PREUNI'], 2, ',', '').'</td>
                            <td>'.number_format($item['VLRLIQ'], 2, ',', '').'</td>
                        </tr>';
            }

            echo '</tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
```

O código da Model:

```
   public function TotalentSaiComNota($codEmp, $codFil, $numPed){
    $sql = "SELECT
                USU_VLRMOE
            FROM 
                E140IPV 
            WHERE 
                CODEMP = ? 
            AND 
                CODFIL = ?
            AND 
                NUMNFV = ?";

    $sql = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $sql->execute(array($codEmp, $codFil, $numPed));

    return $sql->fetch();
}
```

Resumindo preciso que não repita o item do select como está repetindo, preciso que traga os item do select

1. item 1
2. item 2
3. item 3

e não

1. item 1
2. item 1
3. item 1

como está vindo : [image: A imagem está vindo com 4.08, 4.08, 4.08 e deveria estar 4.08, 2.09, 2.09]

Como deveria vir: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O seu loop é em cima de `$itemNFSaida`, não do resultado dessa query que mostrou.

Comment: então coloquei o restante da classe, caso possa ajudar, agradeço

Comment: Os dados estão vindo do método `getItemNFEntrada` ou `getItemNFSaida` do seu modelo. É tudo que dá pra dizer.

Comment: o problema ocorre quando tenho que colocar o if, quando o codme != '01' ele faz um novo select trazendo o valor correto, porem não está funcionando